# Vercel API NET_ERROR

Tags: javascript, vercel

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOcmi.png)

```
//utils/api.js
import axios from 'axios';
const path = "http://(express api ip):8000"

export const newIdGenerate = () => {
     return axios.get(path+"/api/generateid")
     .then(result => {
         return result.data.nextid;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
})  
}
```

In localhost, It work but in vercel, it didn't;

How can i solve it?

express server is hosting in AWS.
It work.

I try CORS setting

```
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
swcMinify: true,
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/api/:path*",
      destination: "http://(ip):8000/api/:path*",
    },
  ];
},  
}
```

Comment: Please post the error as text.